# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created. C# win form

Tags: c#, wcf, events

hi i want to change label when i type in my browser one link. I create wcf service and i use one thread to change label in main form. Now when i click url in browser http://:5001/Connect i get this error for a reason. I dont understand the error here.

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window
>   handle has been created.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Must create object CashDesk_Form ? What must to do. Here is my codes:

MY FORM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace tameio
{
    public partial class CashDesk_Form : Form
    {
        //Αντικείμενα
        ServiceHost host;
        public WCFService wcf;

        //Μεταβλητές
        string WCFPort = "5001";

        //(ΔΗΜΙΟΥΡΓΟΣ) του Server
        public CashDesk_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread startServerThread = new Thread(StartWCFServer);
            startServerThread.IsBackground = true;
            startServerThread.Start();
            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CashDesk_Form_FormClosed);
        }

        void CashDesk_Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                try { host.Close(); }
                catch { }
                host = null;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Ο Server είναι ήδη Απενεργοποιημένος");
        }

        public void AddNewConnection()
        {
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_AddNewConnection));
            clientThread.IsBackground = true;
            clientThread.Start();
        }
        public void _AddNewConnection()
        {
            if (!IsHandleCreated)
                this.CreateControl();

   // ---->   Exception here
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lbl_connectClients.Text = "ASDASDASD";

            });

        }

        //(FUNCTION) - > Εκκίνηση του Server
        private void StartWCFServer()
        {
            if (host == null)
            {
                Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:" + WCFPort + "/");
                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), baseAddress);
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), new WSHttpBinding(), "Services");
                try
                {
                    host.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e.GetType().FullName.ToString() == "System.InvalidOperationException") return;
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Βεβαιωθείτε ότι έχετε δικαιώματα διαχειριστή σε αυτόν τον υπολογιστή");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Υπήρξε πρόβλημα κατά του άνοιγμα του WCF Server. Είτε ο WCF Server είναι Ενεργός, είτε το Port: " + WCFPort + " χρεισιμοποιείτε κάπου αλλού, είτε η IP του δικτύου δεν είναι σωστή");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

WCFService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace tameio
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class WCFService : CashDesk_Form, IWCFService
    {

        public string connect()
        {
            AddNewConnection();
            return "Έχετε συνδεθεί επιτυχώς με την εφαρμογή του ταμείου";
        }
    }
}
```

IWCFService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
namespace tameio
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "SendMessage")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "Connect")]
            //UriTemplate = "Send?Message={txt}")]
        string connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: what *exactly* is the error you are getting (and where are you getting it)?

Comment: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.InvalidOperationException was unhandled. At this code: this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lbl_connectClients.Text = "ASDASDASD";

            });

Comment: Why i get -1 ? Because i dont understand what must to do? I did what exatly says first answer and still dont working

Answer (score 0):

Try and move the startup of the service to a later time:

```
public partial class CashDesk_Form : Form
{

   public CashDesk_Form()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CashDesk_Form_FormClosed);
   }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
       //at this point the handle *is* created

       base.OnShown(e);
       Thread startServerThread = new Thread(StartWCFServer);
       startServerThread.IsBackground = true;
       startServerThread.Start();
    }
 }
```

The exception you are getting i becuase you are starting up the WCF service in your forms constructor. At that point the handle for the Form has not yet been created - and therefore calling `Connect` could lead the the exception you are getting

Comment: How can i use this function? i dont understand. What is base.OnShown();

Comment: I understand why you have made this recommendation, but it's not obvious as to why this fixes solves the problem. You need to provide some explanation.

Comment: I 'd like to give you explanation. I want to change label when i click the link in browser. I thought that this probably can made with event or thread. I try to made with event but i cant. Now i'm trying with thread and if i use MessageBox.Show("message"); inside in Invoke((MethodInvoker) message show normally. But the label didnt change at that point

Comment: Ok and how can i solve? I put the startServerThread in button and i get same exception.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right - I have updated the answer

Comment: @Achill if the messabox works - try and call `this.Refresh()` after you have updated the label inside the invoke.

Comment: base.OnShown(); no overload for method. How must to use this function ?

Comment: @Achill sry - you need to parse `e`like this: `base.OnShown(e)`